# How to create a Spring session scoped bean based on user properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-bean, session-scope

I've developed a Spring Web-MVC application. I have some offices in my project. Each user belongs to an office. `user.getOfficeType()` returns an integer representing the user's office type. If the office type is 1, the user belongs to Office1 and etc.
However I want to inject the authenticated user's office into my service classes:

```
class MyService{
   @Autowired
   Office currentOffice;
   ...
}
```

I read the Spring docs. I need a session scoped bean to inject it into my service classes.

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.package.service" />
...
<bean id="office" class="com.package.beans.Office" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

[image]

I have three implementations of the `Office` interface. Once a user requests a resource, I want to be aware of his Office. So I need to inject his session-scoped Office into my service classes. But I don't know how to instantiate it according to the user's office. please help!

Comment: Is a User session bean too?

Comment: No, It is an entity. I can access it by `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution! I declared an `OfficeContext` that wraps the `Office` and also implements it.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class OfficeContext implements InitializingBean, Office {

   private Office office;

   @Autowired
   private UserDao userDao;

   @Autowired
   private NoneOffice noneOffice;
   @Autowired
   private AllOffice allOffice;
   @Autowired
   private TariffOffice tariffOffice;
   @Autowired
   private ArzeshOffice arzeshOffice;

    public Office getOffice() {
       return this.office;
    }

   @Override
   public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
           String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
           JUser user = userDao.findByUsername(name);
           if (user != null) {
               this.office = noneOffice;
           } else {
               OfficeType type = user.getOfficeType();
               switch (type) {
                   case ALL:
                       this.office = allOffice;
                       break;
                   case TARIFF:
                       this.office = tariffOffice;
                       break;
                   case ARZESH:
                       this.office = arzeshOffice;
                       break;
                   default:
                       this.office = noneOffice;
               }
           }
       } else {
           this.office = noneOffice;
       }

   }

   @Override
   public OfficeType getType() {
       return office.getType();
   }

   @Override
   public String getDisplayName() {
       return office.getDisplayName();
   }

}
```

and in my service classes I injected the `OfficeContext`.

```
@Service
public class UserService {

   @Autowired
   UserDao userDao;

   @Autowired
   OfficeContext office;

   public void persist(JUser user) {
       userDao.persist(user);
   }

   public void save(JUser user) {
       userDao.save(user);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just throwing a different approach

```
@Configuration
public class SessionScopeBeansConfig {

    @Bean
    @SessionScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public User user( UserDAO userDAO ) {

        return userDAO.getUserByLoginName( SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() );
    }


    @Bean
    @SessionScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Office office( User user ) {

        Office office = <<Code to initialize office>>;

        return office;
    }
}
```

This way it's possible to directly inject the `Office`

```
class MyService{
   @Autowired
   Office currentOffice;
   ...
}
```